# Ubuntu Battery not charging or not detected

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery, fan

Here is question/answer just to help the community.

I just bought a new ASUS N750J . I had some issues installing kubuntu. Problems were the CPU FAN always running at full speed, battery not charging, not even detected...

I had difficulties to find a solution over the Internet. I have found it after two days of searching.

Comment: Please separate your question form your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Everything was be related to ACPI (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface) in my case.

On my configuration ASUS N750J with kubuntu 13.x but I suspect on a lot of new laptop with some "smart" energy managers, the solution was to edit your GRUB entry and add the following parameter:

```
acpi=nolapic
```

GRUB is your boot screen, (default config, recovery config, etc). TO edit it, select the entry (or keep the default one) and press "e".

I have found various "solutions" some hacks like "pluggin/unplugging your power source 8 times and things like that. Most don't work and some only provide a temporary relief. The problem is at a very low level, some acpi tables get corrupted while dealing with the hardware. Somehow this parameter fixed my problem.

Comment: Should this be `noapic` (without the `l`)? See e.g. [What are the "acpi" and "noapic" kernel boot options?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/58790)

Comment: Can confirm, on my Lenovo Ideapad 3 running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS adding the line `acpi=noapic` at the end of my `/etc/default/grub` file worked.